# AJAX call is only sending last item, and not entire array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

This is my AJAX call :

```
$(".all_of_union").live("click", function(){
      id = window.location.href.split("/")[5]

      var data = {};
    data.value = $(".union input").map(function(){
        return $(this).val();
    }).get();
    data.type = 'zip';

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/admin/emails/" + id + "/distributions",
        dataType: "script",
        data: data
    });
});
```

If I were to do `alert(data.value)` in my console, then it reveals all the zip codes correctly. But with my breakpoint carefully selected in my Rails application, when it hits the controller, only the last zip code actually shows up.

Even if I send the AJAX call like so :

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/admin/emails/" + id + "/distributions",
      dataType: "script",
      data: { value: ["07005", "07034", "07035", "07045", "07046", "07054", "07058", "07082", "07405", "07435", "07438", "07440", "07444", "07457", "07460", "07801", "07803", "07806", "07828", "07830", "07834", "07836", "07840", "07847", "07849", "07850", "07852", "07853", "07856", "07857", "07866", "07869", "07876", "07885", "07920", "07927", "07928", "07930", "07931", "07932", "07933", "07934", "07935", "07936", "07940", "07945", "07946", "07950", "07960", "07976", "07980", "07981", "07999", "07802", "07842", "07845", "07870", "07878", "07926", "07961", "07962", "07963", "07970"], type: data.type }
  });
```

The results:

```
{"authenticity_token"=>"bMmx0pnJ6ePq6ogwSCR1JH55U7wtrMEOy6ME4rNRmCI=",
 "action"=>"create",
 "type"=>"undefined",
 "value"=>"07970",
 "controller"=>"admin/distributions",
 "email_id"=>"3"}
```

Still only the last zip code shows.

Or I can dumb it down as simple as this :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/admin/emails/" + id + "/distributions",
    dataType: "script",
    data: { value: ['1', '2'] }
});
```

Only `2` will return.

I can't reasonably understand this. Anyone else?

Comment: Have you used Firebug or TamperData to see exactly what the HTTP POST parameters look like?  The issue is going to be that the "value" parameter has to be repeated, once for each zip code.  HTTP allows that but your server-side code has to expect it and handle that. Alternatively, jQuery might be turning the single parameter into a bunch of parameters with ammended names like "value[0]", "value[1]", etc.

Comment: I'm using Rails console to see the HTTP POST parameters. Not really sure how to set it up to "expect" it, as its just reading an HTTP POST basically without Rails, or anything to do with server-side code, and the zips are now showing. If it were turning it to value[0], or value[1], those would be showing up in my params as well. I'll post what I'm looking at above for results.

Comment: Well I would encourage you to use something at the **browser** end to see how the HTTP request starts out. From the Rails side, it may be too late. Personally I like TamperData, but the Firebug console should also show you the request contents.

Comment: Yes in firebug in the HTTP POST, many values of the zip codes are being sent correctly.

Comment: I tried your static call on my rails app, and I actually do get all the zips. Which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: OK well if they're leaving the browser intact, then the problem is not with your JavaScript code. I'm not a Rails person so unfortunately I can't offer any suggestions :(

Comment: @Terw, jquery 1.3.2.. Strange..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this

```
traditional: true
```

EDIT:

I tried your example and got it to work.
Here is the script:

```
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/home/test/" + 4,
    dataType: "script",
    traditional: true,
    data: { value: ['1', '2'] }
  });
```

And here is the method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Test(string id, string[] value)
{
  return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

I get two values in array "value"

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?