# Data Transfer From JavaScript App to Rails Server

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a JavaScript app that produces a string. I want to transfer this string back to my server and assign it to a particular attribute. Apparently AJAX can accomplish this. Unfortunately, I'm a novice with both Rails and AJAX, and I can't find any clear instructions on how to implement the transfer. Is there a simple, standard way to send a string to a Rails server and assign it to a model attribute?

At the moment, the code is inserted directly in my JavaScript function. It looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/bookcases/'+window.location.href.split('/')[4],
  data: {'_method':'put', 'bookcase[imagemap]':mapcode},
  dataType: 'html',
  success: function() {alert( "Data Saved" );}
});
```

Firebug gives me a 404 Not Found error. I've tinkered with the URL a bit, replacing 'edit' with likely candidates like the name of the attribute and POST. I've also removed 'edit' all together. So far I consistently get the same error. The only exception is when I set the URL to '/', at which point the success message pops up. Unfortunately, the mapcode data has not actually been implanted.

Comment: Question is too broad, have you been able to create an AJAX request yet?

Comment: I haven't, though I have a sense of what the code would look like based on [this link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/ajax_on_rails.html) and [this link](http://www.activars.com/2009/04/13/pass-javascript-variables-to-rails-controller/). I'm unsure where to insert this code, though.

Comment: You should improve the question with something you've tried and didn't work. Questions that show you've tried something are more likely to be answered

Comment: I've updated the question with a code snippet. I'm basing this code on a question I found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512744/ajax-call-is-only-sending-last-item-and-not-entire-array).

Comment: Question. Is the "Javascript App" and the Rails App two completely different thing? Or are you just trying to implement a javascript action in your rails app?

Comment: The JavaScript is not in the asset pipeline, but executed directly from a Rails view. (Bad practice, I know, but putting it in the pipeline was causing a whole host of errors.)

Comment: I believe I'm on the right path. After reading Stevo's comment [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag), I think I've got the right parameters plugged in. I'm still getting the 404 error, but I think it might be due to something in my routes.rb file. If you think that's the case, I'll post it. Right now, the bookcase route is generically set at "resources :bookcases".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! Apparently, the above code was working just fine. I just needed to add an update method to my controller. For those working through a similar issue, Firefox's Firebug is invaluable. If you're encountering an error in JavaScript, Firebug will show you what the cause is. I couldn't have figured this out without it.